# Dispatching Redux Saga Actions right after store initialization instead of useEffect

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

We have a react app which Redux + Saga for State Management + Data Fetching.

Currently, we initialize the state and call all the initial API's in the useEffect of the root App Component. This causes a lot of rerenders, and some additional delay.

I was wondering if it would be safe and not an anti pattern to initialize the state from the Local Storages and pass it as the initial store state as well as dispatching redux saga actions right in file where we create the store rather in the useEffect of the root component.

I know it doesn't avoid rerenders but I was thinking it would reduce the delay caused by the initial rendering.

Comment: Sounds perfectly fine, just make sure that all this initialization happens before the first render, otherwise the changed redux state could still cause some rerenders.

Comment: @MartinKadlec Thanks for your input. Will it hamper render time if we hit the API calls for the saga right in the store initialization file? I am a bit new to react so was asking.

Comment: The only thing that could affect the render performance is parsing of the response json if its very very large, but the first render should be done by then so generally its not something I would worry about.